# How to compare numpy arrays ignoring nans?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison

I need to compare if two numpy arrays are equal to a desired precision ignoring nan values.
For example:

```
a = [1,nan,3,nan]  
b = [1,0.2,3,4.1]
```

Should pass the test.
I have tried using numpy.all function but i understand that it expects two array identical and i need to have some tolerance because float values may differ a little.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.allclose` and `np.isnan`:

```
mask = ~(np.isnan(a) | np.isnan(b))
np.allclose(a[mask], b[mask])
```

This correctly handles `+/- inf` and allows for small differences. Absolute and relative tolerances can be specified as parameters to `allclose`.

Answer (score 1):

**Integer Arrays**
Mask your arrays using `np.isfinite` and compare with `np.array_equal`:

```
def array_nan_equal(a, b):
    m = np.isfinite(a) & np.isfinite(b)
    return np.array_equal(a[m], b[m])
```

```
assert array_nan_equal(
     np.array([1, np.nan, 3, np.nan]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
)
assert not array_nan_equal(
     np.array([1, 4, 3, np.nan]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
)
```

Note that if you want to account for +/-`inf`, you can follow the cue in @Paul Panzer's answer and use `m = ~(np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b))` instead of `np.isfinite`.

---

**Floating Point Arrays**
For floats, you'd need to compare within a tolerance, so substitute `np.array_equal` with a call to `np.allclose`:

```
def array_nan_close(a, b):
    m = np.isfinite(a) & np.isfinite(b)
    return np.allclose(a[m], b[m])
```

```
assert array_nan_close(
     np.array([1.3, np.nan, 3.4, np.nan]), np.array([1.3000001, 2, 3.4, 4])
)
assert not array_nan_close(
     np.array([1.1, 4.0, 3.5, np.nan]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by that shape check?

Comment: @PaulPanzer look at what being tired makes you do.. unfortunately now it resembles your answer a bit too much, so if you're uncomfortable with it, please feel free to edit it out of my answer. Cheers. Also passing you a vote.